# Exception caught by widgets library - Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, android-widget, dart-null-safety

On the sign-up page when the user enters the email that was used before,  this exception happens (Null check operator used on a null value)

[firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

this is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toto/main.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class CreateAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateAccountState createState() => _CreateAccountState();
}

class _CreateAccountState extends State<CreateAccount> {
  //FirebaseAuth fireauth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  //FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _Key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final ageController = TextEditingController();
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final numericRegex = RegExp(r'[0-9]');
  final CharRegex = RegExp(r'[!@#\$&*~]');
  final LetterRegex = RegExp(r'[a-z A-Z]');
  bool isVisible = false;
  var errorMessage = '';

//--------------------------------------validations-----------------------

  String? validateName(String? formName) {
    final nameRegex = RegExp(
        r'^[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z]+[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FFa-zA-Z-_]{1,20}$');

    if (formName == null || formName.isEmpty)
      return 'الاسم مطلوب';
    else if (!nameRegex.hasMatch(formName))
      return 'يجب أن يتكون الأسم من حروف فقط';
    else
      return null;
  }

  String? validateEmail(String? formEmail) {
    if (formEmail == null || formEmail.isEmpty)
      return 'البريد الالكتروني مطلوب';

    String pattern = r'\w+@\w+\.\w+';
    RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(formEmail))
      return 'صيغة البريد الالكتروني غير صحيحة';
    else
      return null;

    
  }

  String? validatePassword(String? formPassword) {
    if (formPassword == null || formPassword.isEmpty)
      return 'كلمة المرور مطلوبة';
    else if (formPassword.length < 8)
      return 'يجب ان تحتوي كلمة السر على 8 خانات أو أكثر';
    else if (!numericRegex.hasMatch(formPassword) &&
        !LetterRegex.hasMatch(formPassword))
      return 'يجب أن تحتوي كلمة المرور على أرقام وحروف';
    else
      return null;

    
  }

  bool obscure_text = true;
  Icon iconfirst = Icon(
    Icons.visibility_off,
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
  );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body:
            //SafeArea(
            Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,

          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 35.0),
          //padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 70, 0, 0),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/housebg.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                key: _Key,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 90,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "تسجيل حساب جديد",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 33.0,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 22, 13),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: "ElMessiri"),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    ),

                    //------------------------------name---------------------------------------
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 30, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "الاسم",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 75, 12),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    TextFormField(
                      controller: nameController,
                      validator: validateName,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      cursorColor: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        counterText: "",
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          color: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                        ),
                        hintText: "الاسم",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF909A99),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    //------------------------age---------------------
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 30, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "العمر",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 75, 12),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    TextFormField(
                      controller: ageController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      cursorColor: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        counterText: "",
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.calendar_month,
                          color: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                        ),
                        hintText: "العمر",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF909A99),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),

                    //------------------------Username-----------------------------
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 30, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "اسم المستخدم",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 75, 12),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: usernameController,
                      validator: (value) {
                        ////////// validator /////////////
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'يجب ادخال اسم المستخدم';
                        } else if (value.contains('0')) {
                          // اشيك في الداتابيس
                          return 'اسم المستخدم محجوز';
                        } else
                          return null;
                      },
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                        filled: true,
                        counterText: "",
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.account_box,
                          color: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                        ),
                        hintText: "اسم المستخدم",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF909A99),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    //-----------------------------email----------------------------------
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 30, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "البريد الإلكتروني",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 75, 12),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: emailController,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: validateEmail,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      cursorColor: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                        counterText: "",
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.mail,
                          color: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                        ),
                        hintText: 'email@address.com',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF909A99),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    ),

                    //-------------------------------password-----------------------------
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 30, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        "كلمة المرور",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 75, 12),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    TextFormField(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      validator: validatePassword,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      obscureText: obscure_text,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                        counterText: "",
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        suffixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                        ),
                        prefixIcon: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (obscure_text == true) {
                                obscure_text = false;
                                iconfirst = Icon(
                                  Icons.visibility,
                                  color: Color(0xFF90B28D),
                                );
                              } else {
                                obscure_text = true;
                                iconfirst = Icon(
                                  Icons.visibility_off,
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                                );
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: iconfirst,
                        ),
                        hintText: "كلمة المرور",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF909A99),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        register(emailController.text.trim(),
                            passwordController.text);
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          fixedSize: Size(280, 40),
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFA03C1B),
                          elevation: 0.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(30),
                            ),
                          )),
                      child: Text(
                        "تسجيل ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                            fontSize: 22.0,
                            color: Colors.white),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),

                    //////////////////////////////////////// have an account
                    Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: main,
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "تسجيل دخول",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                                    fontSize: 16.0,
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "لديك حساب؟",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: "ElMessiri",
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void register(String email, String password) async {
    if (_Key.currentState!.validate()) {
      try {
        await _auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
            .then((value) => {postDetailsToFirestore()});
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        print(error);
        errorMessage = error.message!;
        Map<String, String?> codeResponses = {
          // Re-auth responses
          "user-mismatch": 'المستخدم غير متطابق',
          "user-not-found": 'لم يتم العثور على المستخدم',
          "invalid-credential": 'invalid credential',
          "invalid-email": 'الايميل غير موجود',
          "wrong-password": 'كلمة المرور الحالية خاطئة',
          "invalid-verification-code": 'رمز التحقق غير صالح',
          "invalid-verification-id": 'معرّف التحقق غير صالح',
          "user-disabled": 'المستخدم لهذا الايميل معطّل',
          "too-many-requests": 'طلبات كثيرة',
          "operation-not-allowed":
              'تسجيل الدخول من خلال الايميل وكلمة المرور غير مسموح',
          // Update password error codes
          "weak-password": 'كلمة المرور غير قوية',
          "requires-recent-login": 'يتطلب تسجيل دخول حديث'
        };
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                  content: Text(codeResponses[error.code]!),
                  actions: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'حسنًا'),
                      child: const Text('حسنًا'),
                    )
                  ]);
            });
      }
    }
  }

  postDetailsToFirestore() async {
    User? user = _auth.currentUser;

    try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user?.uid).set({
        'userID': user?.uid,
        'name': nameController.text,
        'age': ageController.text,
        'username': usernameController.text,
        'email': emailController.text,
      });
     

      print(nameController.text);
      print(ageController.text);
      print(usernameController.text);
      print(emailController.text);
      //if(ageController.text>='60'){
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil((context),
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => home()), (route) => false);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      errorMessage = error.message!;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to fix this,

1. Make the below change

```
showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                  // add -> ?? "Unknown Error" to below line
                  content: Text(codeResponses[error.code] ?? "Unknown error"),
                  actions: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'حسنًا'),
                      child: const Text('حسنًا'),
                    )
                  ]);
            });
```

Or

2. Add `email-already-in-use` to `codeResponses`

```
Map<String, String?> codeResponses = {
          // Re-auth responses
          "user-mismatch": 'المستخدم غير متطابق',
          "user-not-found": 'لم يتم العثور على المستخدم',
          "email-already-in-use" : 'Email already in use',
```